# Changing References Folder (Assemblies) to /bin

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, reference, probing

I am trying to change where my DLLs or EXE's have been referenced, and instead of a copylocal, which would place it in the same folder as my application, I need it to be in a subfolder. For example:
  Let's say the path is "*C:\Program Files(x86)\Test\Test.exe*"
  and the DLL it needs to use is "*testDll.dll*"
  instead of Visual Studio placing it in the "*\Test*" folder, i need it to be in "*\Test\bin*"

I have previously tried the `<Probing>` element in my vbackup.exe.config file, but it didn't end up working, with one of my settings giving me a "System.Configuration.dll" error, I can't remember the error exactly, and i got a warning saying about the `<configuration>` element is not declared.
Another solution i tried was to put "`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath = "bin"`" in my main.vb but that didn't do anything, and i wasn't sure which sub to put it in.

Any help will be greatly appreciated,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

It isn't `<Probing>`. It is `<probing>`. XML is case-sensitive.

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

should do it, in the `Test.exe.config` file.

Comment: Okay, So I've tried that code but I get an exception:A first chance exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll

Additional information: Configuration system failed to initialize

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued
and highlights "Return CType(Me("lang"),String)" in settings.designer.vb